# WCF and Entity Framework with Telerik GridModel

Tags: c#, wcf, telerik

This is cross-posted on [Telerik's support forums](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-mvc/grid/wcf-and-entity-framework-with-gridmodel.aspx).

I have an Entity Framework (Code First, 4.1) context that is used in a WCF service layer.  If I have the service set up this way:

```
public IEnumerable<Dto.PlanMember> GetPlanMembers() {
    var planMembers = from member in this.DataSource.PlanMemberDbSet.Take(10)
                      select new Dto.PlanMember {
                          Id = member.Id,
                          FirstName = member.FirstName,
                          LastName = member.LastName
                      };

    return planMembers;
}
```

The service works fine.  If I set it up like this, following [the examples for grid binding via web services](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/webservice)...

```
public GridModel GetPlanMembers(GridState state) {
    var planMembers = from member in this.DataSource.PlanMemberDbSet.Take(10)
                      select new Dto.PlanMember {
                          Id = member.Id,
                          FirstName = member.FirstName,
                          LastName = member.LastName
                      };

    return planMembers.ToGridModel(state);
}
```

It consistently get the exception:

> The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed
>   unexpectedly.

I'm certain this is a serialization issue.  For whatever reason the `ToGridModel` extension method isn't working properly with EFCF 4.1.  What can be done to fix this?

This doesn't work either, so it must be related to serializing the `GridModel` type and not the extension method itself that's the problem:

```
public GridModel GetPlanMembers(GridState state) {
    var planMembers = from member in this.DataSource.PlanMemberDbSet.Take(10)
                      select new Dto.PlanMember {
                          Id = member.Id,
                          FirstName = member.FirstName,
                          LastName = member.LastName
                      };

    var gridModel = new GridModel {
        Data = planMembers,
        Total = planMembers.Count()
    };

    return gridModel;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that LINQ queries have delayed execution.  So you are returning an IQueryable.  The data is not actually retrieved until WCF tries to serialize it.  The problem is that your connection is already closed at that point.  Throw a `.ToList()` on there and you should be good.

Comment: This was partially correct. It did get me in the right direction, though. In the end I can't use EFCF entities directly as I'm lazy loading. The real object type is the dynamic proxy, which WCF can't serialize. I needed to use data transfer objects.

Comment: If you turn proxy creation and lazy loading off, you can get away with not using DTOs.  You will also want to make sure you add `[DataContract]` attributes to your entities and specify `IsReference = true`.  Otherwise you can run into an issue with cycles in your object graph.  This might still be an issue with DTOs if you include associations.